# RestartFlow.onFailuresWithBackoff not restarting on failure

Tags: akka, akka-stream, alpakka

We are encountering an unexpected behavior from:

```
RestartFlow.onFailuresWithBackoff(restartSetting)(flowFactory: () => Flow[In, Out, _])
```

See [RestartFlow.onFailuresWithBackoff](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/RestartFlow/onFailuresWithBackoff.html).
We're using:

> akka:2.6.15 akka-stream-kafka_2.12:2.1.1 scala:2.12.13.

We're using the following **RestartSettings**:

```
RestartSettings(minBackoff=1.seconds, maxBackoff=900.seconds, randomFactor=0.5
  ).withMaxRestarts(maxRestarts=8, maxRestartsWithin=1.seconds)
```

**Expected behavior:** The wrapped flow which is wrapped with **RestartFlow** should restart when failure occurs.

**Actual behavior:** The wrapped flow is not restarting when the failure occurs; it goes to **Supervision.Decider** for the failure.

**Supervision.Decider** is concatenated after the wrapped **RestartFlow** to handle the scenario where the restart got exhausted and the failure can be handled by **Supervision.Decider**.

> Source -> flow1 -> flow2 -> RestartFlow.onFailuresWithBackoff(flow3)
> -> flow4 + (Supervision.Decider) -> Sink